# How can I set the width and height of a container div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="pic.png">
</div>
```

This is styled as follows:

```
#container {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

In addition to this, I have some javascript hackery to cause the image to appear dead center in the containing div by setting `margin-top` and `margin-left`.

When I look at this in the Chrome web inspector, it's clear that the containing div does not start at the top of its parent. I suspect the image is being positioned relative to the container div's parent.

The trouble with this is that I want the container div to be a target for click events, such as dragging. The div only starts at the top of the image, when I want it to start above the image, and include the margin space as a part of the container. Any advice?

Comment: Why not show the whole code? Makes it a lot easier to evaluate :) You probably need to use hide the overflow or use a CSS background (with coordinates) in the div instead of an `img`-tag inside it.

Comment: Please provide the html and css and if you're reaaally awesome a jsfiddle too ;)

Comment: `div.container` is the wrong selector for your element. Use `#container`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@plalx is right your using the wrong selector you should just do this:

```
#container{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

`padding` is what your looking for with making the div bigger then the image for click. `margin` determines place on the page, `padding` determines *space* on the page beyond your `height` and `width` attributes.

See http://jsfiddle.net/VRJUc/. If you open the element inspector (chrome) and look at the actual size of the div you will see that it is actually `60x60` because I have added `5px` of padding to each side.